# Обрезка ссылки python

Tags: python

У меня есть ссылка по типу: https://example.com/example/example/2041674-Craps/313553930-Player-1-Player-2/

Мне нужно обрезать эту ссылку чтобы остались вот эти цифры -> 313553930

Обратить это всё в список и получать всё по индексу не выйдет потому, что ссылка меняется ежедневно и вместо https://example.com/ может быть https://example-123.com/ поэтому получится смещение и это не подходит.

Answer (score 4):

Можно регуляркой вытаскивать, например:

```
import re

urls = [
    'https://example.com/example/example/2041674-Craps/313553930-Player-1-Player-2/',
    'https://example-123.com/example/2041674-Craps/313553930-Player-1-Player-2/',
]

for url in urls:
    items = re.findall(r'/(\d+)-Player', url)
    print(items[-1])
```

Comment: а разве не получится в результате `1` ? Там же строка `...30-Player-1-Player-2/`

Comment: @ZaArs, там есть `/` перед цифрами

Comment: не заметил, вопросов нет)

Comment: Спасибо за решение проблемы

Comment: @Mark_Markov, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 3):

Ну такой ещё вариант для разнообразия. Хотя из-за того, что в конце ссылки может быть или не быть `/` пришлось лишний `filter` писать на всякий случай:

```
url = "https://example.com/example/example/2041674-Craps/313553930-Player-1-Player-2/"
print(list(filter(len, url.split('/')))[-1].split('-')[0])
# 313553930
```

Если `/` в конце точно всегда есть, то гораздо короче можно написать:

```
print(url.split('/')[-2].split('-')[0])
```

Ну или так ещё с убиранием `/` если он есть, по совету insolor:

```
print(url.rstrip('/').split('/')[-1].split('-')[0])
```

Comment: Достаточно rstrip сделать перед split, тогда filter не нужен будет

Comment: @insolor А, точно, не сообразил

Answer (score 0):

Через регулярки можно еще через `re.search()` вытащить, хотя `re.findall` будет удобнее, не выдавая ошибку при пустом поиске.

```
import re

urls = [
    'https://example.com/example/example/2041674-Craps/313553930-Player-1-Player-2/',
    'https://example-123.com/example/2041674-Craps/313553930-Player-1-Player-2/',
]

for url in urls:
    items = re.search('/(\d+)-Player', url).group(1)
    print(items)
```

Можно еще через `split()` строки с поиском вхождения `Player`

```
for url in urls:
    for url in urls:
print(next((v.split('-')[0] for v in url.split('/') if 'player' in v.lower()), None))
```

Во всех случаях имеем вывод:

```
313553930
313553930
```